# How to bold text With Compact Framework

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, compact-framework, bold

I have an app written in C# for the compact framework (3.5).

I am trying to display some text on the form in bold.

The `Label` class does not give me the option to bold my text (I can make it bigger, which eventually gives a bold look, but I want my text 12pt and bold.

Is this possible?  If so How?

thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it designtime ;)

In visual studio you can extend the font property, to expose the name, font and style property.
Also you can add `; style=bold` after the font property in visual studio. (or any style for that matter).

If you keep using the code above, i recommend disposing the old font, to prevent a memory leak

Answer (score 3):

[FontStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.style.aspx) should work for you

```
Label1.Font = new Font(Label1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
```

Comment: Sweet! That worked.  Kinda lame that I can't do that at design time.  But run time is when it really matters.

Comment: The font isn't an option at design time? I'm pretty sure it is. But I think it is collapsed. You have to click the + and then you will see it.